# Is it possible to switch repository in Mercurial Command Server protocol?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I'm batch processing lots of Mercurial repositories and I want to save CPU time by avoiding `fork`.

I can use internal Mercurial API: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi to create objects operating on several repositories simultaneously in a single Python process address space. But this method is discouraged by Hg maintainers: they consider Python Hg API unstable...

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer is a recommended approach but it requires starting a server per repository: `hg --config ui.interactive=True serve --cmdserver pipe`. Meaning lots of forks that I wanted to avoid...

Is there a way to utilize a single `hg serve --cmdserver pipe` and switch repositories? What is the **control command name** for switching, what is the signature/args?

Comment: If you were able to get the cmd server to switch repositories, why is that better than stopping/starting a new server?

Comment: My goal is to avoid `fork` syscall. It is bottleneck on Windows. I'm experimenting with private `mercurial` package instead.

Comment: Unless the repos are tiny I would have thought the new process creation would be only a very small portion of the overall runtime / cpu work

Comment: Not on windows... I'm working on syncing a set of hg repos. Cygwin or Msys2 have extremely slow `fork`.